# Unmatched '. error while setting up alias

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh

I am setting an alias in Linux to print the history without the serial number and time of the command being run.
This is the command to do that :

```
history | awk '{$1="";$2="";print}'
```

I am looking to set it as an alias and I see issues with Unmatched '.

```
$> alias oh 'history | awk \'{$1="";$2="";print}\''
Unmatched '.
```

Comment: You cannot escape single quotes in a single quoted string: see [Single Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) in the manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use backslash as an escape inside single quotes, only inside double quotes. You need to end the string so you can have the escaped single quotes.

```
alias oh 'history | awk '\''{$1="";$2="";print}'\'
```

Comment: I get this when I use your code:
    Badly placed ()'s.

Comment: What shell are you using? This should work in any POSIX-compatible shell: `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`.

Comment: I am using /bin/tcsh

Comment: I've changed it to a csh solution.

Comment: The solution you posted works. But, I am curios about how that alias works. As you are ending the string after the awk and starting a new string after escaping a single quote , Does it concatenate those two strings ? Can you explain that ?

Comment: Yes, all the strings are concatenated since there's no spaces between them.